# Как сформировать массив из MySQL?

Tags: php

Есть база данных из 1 таблицы (10 столбцов, 1000+ записей).
Как всю таблицу занести в массив вида:

```
array(
  array(1,2,3,,5,6,7,8,9,10), // первая строка
  array(1,2,3,,5,6,7,8,9,10), // вторая строка
  ...
  array(1,2,3,,5,6,7,8,9,10)
)
```

?

Comment: а в чем у вас проблема? Документацию смотрели?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменные, содержащие данные для подключения к бд:

```
$dbname = ''; // Имя бд
$user = ''; // Имя пользователя бд
$pass = ''; // Пароль от бд
```

Подключение к базе и вывод данных в массиве:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname, $user, $pass);
    $select = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table`"); // $db - PDO
    $select->execute();
    $rows = $select->fetchAll(); // $rows - Массив php
    print_r($rows); // Печать массива с инфой из бд
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Ошибка!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, что такое PDO?

Comment: @ВикторПавлов PDO - это расширение `PHP` для работы с базами данных. Поскольку Вы с ним не знакомы, я обновил ответ и все прокомментировал. Пользуйтесь.